# SQLAlchemy read_sql() into Pandas dataframe - large column value gets truncated

Tags: python, mysql, sql, pandas, sqlalchemy

I am trying to read data from a `MySQL` table, and one of the columns contains large varchar values e.g. of length `49085`. When I read the results of the query into a dataframe, the column value is truncated at 87 characters. Please see the code below and the output. Does anyone know how I can read the entire string without truncation?

In the code below table `test` contains a column `description` where one of the rows has a string of length 49085.

Code:

```
import sys
import os
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pandas as pd

db_connection_str = 'mysql+pymysql://username:password@host/db_name'
db_connection = create_engine(db_connection_str)

#this returns 1 row where the value in the description field is of length 49085
df = pd.read_sql("select id, description, length(description) as len from myTable where length(description) = 49085", con=db_connection)

#this returns the truncated value of length 87
print(df)
len(str(df['description']))
```

Output:

```
   id                                             description    len
0  1  This document is for the testing Team.\n\nThe attach...  49085
87
```

Comment: have you treid another driver?

Comment: I haven't, don't know much about that. Do you mean trying something other than `sqlalchemy`?

Comment: yes try mysql.connector

Answer (score 1):

You are being misled by `len(str(df['description']))`. `df['description']` returns a `<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>` object and if we call `str()` on it we get

```
'0    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx...\nName: description, dtype: object'
```

The length of that string will be 87 for any arbitrarily large string in the Series. To test the actual length of the string, use

```py
print(len(df['description'][0]))
```

or similar.

Comment: Thanks! that's helpful to know. I tried `print(len(df['description'][0]))` and it does show the correct length of 49085. But then when I write the `df` to a `.txt` file, I still get the truncated value. Below is the code I'm using to write it to a `.txt` file.

Comment: `writePath = r'sample_data.txt'
with open(writePath, 'a') as f:
    dfAsString = df.to_string(index=False)
    f.writelines(dfAsString)`

Comment: If you're looking to dump the DataFrame to a text file you might have better luck with something like `df.to_csv()`

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but wouldn't that have the same issue? Coz to open the csv I'd need to do that in Excel and the max length of a cell in Excel is 30k characters.

Comment: Many applications other than Excel can consume CSV files. What exactly do you intend to do with that text file?

Comment: Ultimately, I intend to provide the text file as an input into a third-party app. The app then reads the fields and values (i.e. `id` and `description`) and allows the end users to read through the content, search for keywords etc. in a user friendly UI. There'll be several such text files feeding into it. So it's important that the text in `description` doesn't get truncated.

Comment: The docs for the third-party app should offer some guidance, then. Some apps don't deal well with CSV files containing strings with embedded line-breaks; in that case `df_to_json()` might be another option.

Comment: Ok will try `df_to_json()` as well. However, the primary concern still remains the truncation whichever file format the data gets exported out to.